# Where I can find information about windows linker?

Tags: windows, assembly, compilation, linker, reverse-engineering

I need to make hand crafted object file's and then link it with each other under windows. So what is linux .o files, GNU linker and nm windows alternatives?
I've already read this http://www.lurklurk.org/linkers/linkers.html it's great article but analysis of object file covers only linux. So I want to know how translated sources and names becomes object file, and then executable file.

Comment: If you already know and like the GNU tools, use them on Windows.  MinGW gcc and binutils should have all of those tools.

Comment: For info on name mangling and other cross-platform asm differences, see [Agner Fog's assembly guide](http://agner.org/optimize).  See also other links in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)

Comment: The object file format on Windows is called PECOFF. There's probably no need to "hand craft" object files, though, and as Peter Cordes mentioned you can just use the Windows port of the GNU assembler, linker and other utils.